# Android onSensorChanged synchronization

Tags: android, sensors

Is the call to onSensorChanged sequential if my frequency is set to fastest? Should I be synchronising the function? Let's say at time T<sub>0</sub>, T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub> the sensor sensed a change in output. Will onSensorChanged for T<sub>0</sub> get completed and then be called for T<sub>1</sub>and T<sub>2</sub> or their execution might mix up?